# siunitx: Does \qty allow for fractions?

Tags: siunitx

Can I use `\qty` for fractions?

I get an invalid number error.

Comment: Show your MWE for easy clarification

Comment: @DaiBowen yes, many thanks!

Comment: Please read [MWE](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)